# How are the PC-1 & PC-2 calculated for the DES block cipher?

Tags: encryption, des

How  are the permuted choice tables - [PC-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material#Permuted_choice_1_(PC-1)) and [PC-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material#Permuted_choice_2_(PC-2)) - calculated for the DES block cipher algorithm?

Comment: I think they were *established* rather than calculated. Note that the DES / Lucifer cipher wasn't part of an open competition where cryptographers discussed their algorithm freely. So not all design rationale may be known - hopefully somebody can answer this one.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1684/ (one of the group's very first questions!)

Comment: This seems a duplicate of [DES Key Schedule Algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11011/des-key-schedule-algorithm/11927).

Answer (score 1):

These are not calculated, but as with the particulars of S-boxes, suggested and reviewed as part of the design.

These fixed values/configurations are intended to add certain qualities to the particular step of each round, essentially obscuring the final output as much as possible, in a non predictable way. As you can read on Wikipedia, there is some controversy involved in the development of the S-boxes.

> There was some criticism from various parties, including from
>   public-key cryptography pioneers Martin Hellman and Whitfield
>   Diffie,[1] citing a shortened key length and the mysterious "S-boxes"
>   as evidence of improper interference from the NSA.